# Cannot use Web Components more than once

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I'm new to vanilla javascript as i have experience only in reactjs. I'm trying to display a web component i have created in two places. But it displays only once. What can be the issue here?

My web component

```
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        // always call super() first
        super();
        console.log('constructed!');
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        // console.log(this.getAttribute("filter"));
        this.innerHTML = `
          <html>
            <div id="templates" class="template_style">
              <template id="book-template">
                <li><span class="title"></span> &mdash; <span class="author"></span></li>
              </template>

             <ul id="books"></ul>
           </div>

         </html>
       `;
    }
}

customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
```

JS code used to populate the web component with data

```
import JsonObj from './debts.js';

const books = JsonObj;

function appendBooks() {
    const booksList = document.getElementById('books');
    const fragment = document.getElementById('book-template');

    // Clear out the content from the ul
    booksList.innerHTML = '';
    console.log(books);
    // Loop over the books and modify the given template
    books.debts.forEach(book => {
        // Create an instance of the template content
        const instance = document.importNode(fragment.content, true);
        // Add relevant content to the template
        instance.querySelector('.title').innerHTML = book.bank;
        instance.querySelector('.author').innerHTML = book.category;
        // Append the instance ot the DOM
        booksList.appendChild(instance);
    });
}


document.getElementById('templates').addEventListener('change', (event) => appendBooks());

appendBooks('book-template');
```

HTML code where i'm using the above component

```
<div>

    <div class="sub_container">

        <label>Users in Debt</label>

        <input placeholder="Search by user name" class="input_style">

        <my-component filter="userdebt"></my-component>


    </div>

    <div class="sub_container">

        <label>Debts</label>

        <input placeholder="Search by debt description" class="input_style">

        <my-component filter="debt"></my-component>

    </div>

</div>
```

So as seen in the html code i have used `</my-component>` in two places but i can only see the first instance only. I have used a console.log inside constructor in my component and i can see it calls 2 times. But in the view i can see only the first instance. How can i fix this?

Comment: Content inside `<template>` tags are not rendered on the DOM. So how can you say: *But it displays only once* ?

Comment: I have included my js code used to populate the template with data.. can you take a look now?

Comment: Check my answer, and let me know if it worked.

Comment: If you convert your code into a Stack-Snippet everyone can run it inline. See: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/  There is no need to copy/paste code to CodePen or JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `id` to the web-component itself so that you can query using the `id` of the parent for the child nodes that is contained within it

In your code the when queried using the `id` of the child of the web-component it fetched you the first one since you had duplicated ids, in my code I gave each `<my-component>` tag a unique `id` so that I can only query for its child:

```js
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        // always call super() first
        super();
        console.log('constructed!');
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        // console.log(this.getAttribute("filter"));
        this.innerHTML = `
            <div id="templates" class="template_style">
              <template id="book-template">
                <li><span class="title"></span> &mdash; <span class="author"></span></li>
              </template>

             <ul id="books"></ul>
           </div>
       `;
    }
}

customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
const books = [{bank : "foo", category: "bar"}];

function appendBooks(id) {
    const comp = document.getElementById(id);
    //query for the child of the parent web-component
    const booksList = comp.querySelector('#books'); 
    const fragment = comp.querySelector('#book-template');
   

    // Clear out the content from the ul
    booksList.innerHTML = '';
   
    // Loop over the books and modify the given template
    books.forEach(book => {
        // Create an instance of the template content
        const instance = document.importNode(fragment.content, true);
        // Add relevant content to the template
       
        instance.querySelector('.title').innerHTML = book.bank;
        instance.querySelector('.author').innerHTML = book.category;
        // Append the instance ot the DOM
        booksList.appendChild(instance);
    });
}

function addChangeListener(id){
  document.getElementById(id)
          .querySelector('#templates')
          .addEventListener('change', (event) => appendBooks());
}

appendBooks('comp1'); //for componenent having id = comp1
appendBooks('comp2'); //for componenent having id = comp2
addChangeListener('comp1')
addChangeListener('comp2')
```

```html
<div>

    <div class="sub_container">

        <label>Users in Debt</label>

        <input placeholder="Search by user name" class="input_style">

        <my-component id="comp1" filter="userdebt"></my-component>


    </div>

    <div class="sub_container">

        <label>Debts</label>

        <input placeholder="Search by debt description" class="input_style">

        <my-component id="comp2" filter="debt"></my-component>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Your solution was correct. Genius!

Answer (score 0):

I have repeated your code in codepen, and it's work as you expect. Two components are generated. You should check for errors in other places if you have.
And don't use static ids in your component because of duplicates. HTML tag is no need to use too.

Comment: i have updated the question with the JS code i've used to populate my web component with json data.. can you please take a look